# Entering a nucleus

Tags: atoms

If I drive one kilometer along a straight road from A to B in a car that is a simple path.

If I was smaller though (say ant-size) I would have to traverse the road following all the contours in the asphalt. From A to B would be a much greater distance for an ant.

If I was even smaller though I would have to begin navigating the space between particles to get from A to B. At this scale would atoms exert gravitational forces on me and would I be able to enter a nucleus or would electrons prevent me from doing so?

Comment: If your size is comparable to atoms themselves then what are you?

Comment: If you want to enter a nucleus, you need to be a neutrino. In this case all your consciousness will be gone :-)

Comment: @Sam - I guess I am a very small piece of not very clear imagination from an ordinary type of mind : )